# problem with NDSolve using RungeKutta

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm having a problem with using NDSolve.
It might be a simple problem, and related to the method's parameters, yet I'm not sure how.

I have two deferential equations, and I'm trying to get the solution between two points a and b where my B.C. are that both of the function are zero at a and b.
In the code below, for some reason when d=10 there is a solution, yet for d=1, it returns 1/0 encountered. I'm not sure how to fix it and solve for d=1?
I saw that it is related to several factors:

1. step sizes, and maybe max steps.
2. the values of a and b
3. the value of b-a

If I want to get a solution for any a,b that are non zero and positive, how can I fix the other parameters so the code would give me an answer for any value of d?

The code:

---

```
a = 0.5; b = 1;
e = 100; d = 10;
sol = NDSolve[{u''[x] == -(1/x)*(u'[x]) - (h'[x])*(h''[x]), (h''[x])*((3/2)*(h'[x])^2 + u'[x]) 
+ h'[x]*u''[x] + d/e == 0, u[a] == 0, u[b] == 0, h[a] == 0, h[b] == 0}, {u[x], h[x]}, {x,a,b}, 
   Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta", MaxSteps -> \[Infinity], StartingStepSize -> 0.001];
U[x_] := Evaluate[u[x] /. sol[[1, 1]]]; 
H[x_] := Evaluate[h[x] /. sol[[1, 2]]];
Plot[{Evaluate[U[x]], Evaluate[H[x]]}, {x, a, b}]
```

---

Comment: Code works fine for `a=1/2` and ` StartingStepSize ->10^-3`. So you can  try rational numbers as input parameters.

Comment: It still does not work for d=1

Comment: See my answer with possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

We can use different options when try to solve BVP, for instance

```
a = 1/2; b = 1;
e = 100; d = 1;
sol = NDSolve[{u''[
      x] == -(1/x)*(u'[x]) - (h'[x])*(h''[x]), (h''[
         x])*((3/2)*(h'[x])^2 + u'[x]) + h'[x]*u''[x] + d/e == 0, 
    u[a] == 0, u[b] == 0, h[a] == 0, h[b] == 0}, {u[x], h[x]}, {x, a, 
    b}, Method -> "ExplicitEuler", MaxSteps -> \[Infinity], 
   StartingStepSize -> 10^-3];
U[x_] := Evaluate[u[x] /. sol[[1, 1]]];
H[x_] := Evaluate[h[x] /. sol[[1, 2]]];
Plot[{Evaluate[U[x]], Evaluate[H[x]]}, {x, a, b}, PlotLegends -> {"U", "H"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]